# best offline viewer for log4j2 file appender

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2

i have a bunch of logs arriving from elsewhere (not online, these are offline logs created in the past with a log4j2 rolling file appender)

I am looking for some tool to help me browse through these logs (a visual tool)

is there something out there that does that? again, I cant configure anything on site -> I already have the logs on my pc...

I have read some posts regarding this but many tools I am not sure fit my needs and many are completely out dated.

your help is appreciated.